# AndEngine BoundCamera not chasing entity in right way

Tags: android, camera, andengine

I have customized BoundCamera and have overrided the update method as:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    if(chaseEntity != null) {

        tempHeight = (chaseEntity.getY() * PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT) + PlayLevelActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT/2;

        if(tempHeight < heightCovered) {
            setBounds(0, 0, PlayLevelActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH, tempHeight);

            heightCovered = tempHeight;
        }
    }

}
```

and have initialized the camera as:

```
mCamera = new MyBoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 0, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

I want to keep chase entity in center all time. Now the problem I am facing is that in start, the camera chases the entity. As the entity goes higher and higher, it goes beyond screen bounds in y direction. I am updating camera bounds in on update method to keep entity always in center but not working. The chaseEntity.getY() gets the physics body y position. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: AndEngine already has a function providing the functionallity required. It's been a while but I believe its something like: *this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(Sptite);*

Comment: I have already set chasing entity.

Comment: then the camera you be following the entity without you having to update the camera manually?

Comment: Actually I have to track the height the entity has covered and don't want entity to fall the height covered. I have a similar case as in PapiJump game where papi always remains in center.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(Sptite);
setBoundsEnabled(false);
```

then the sprite will still be in the center of the screen all the time. The downside is that the sprite can go beyond the bounds. You would have to implement your own method to keep the sprite within the bounds.

In the comments you mentioned that at some point you want the sprite to fall but don't want it to remain in the center while it is falling. You could just use

```
this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(null);
```

then drop the sprite to the bottom of the screen. That should provide an effect similar to papi jump.